# Pandas merge columns with similar prefixes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with binary columns that looks like this:

```
DEM_HEALTH_PRIV  DEM_HEALTH_PRE  DEM_HEALTH_HOS  DEM_HEALTH_OUT
0                        1             0              0
0                        0             1              1
```

I want to take the suffix of each variable and convert the binary variables to one categorical variable that corresponds with the prefix. For example, merge all DEM_HEALTH variables to include a list of "PRE", "HOS", "OTH" etc. where the value of the column is equal to 1.

```
Output
DEM_HEALTH_PRIV 
['PRE']                      
['HOS','OUT']
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post a reproducible dataset sample for others to help you with the code

Comment: how do you want to combine the `"PRE", "HOS", "OTH"` columns? just a OR operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
#original dataframe is called df

new_cols = [tuple(i.rsplit('_',1)) for i in df.columns]
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)
df.columns = new_cols
data = df[df==1]\
        .stack()\
        .reset_index(-1)\
        .groupby(level=0)['level_1']\
        .apply(list)
```

---

### Explanation

IIUC your data looks something like the following

```
print(df)

   DEM_HEALTH_PRIV  DEM_HEALTH_OUT  DEM_HEALTH_PRE  DEM_HEALTH_HOS
0                0               1               1               1
1                0               1               0               0
2                0               0               1               0
3                0               1               0               0
4                1               0               0               0
5                0               0               1               1
6                1               0               1               0
7                1               0               0               1
8                0               1               0               0
9                0               1               1               0
```

#### 1. Create multi-index by rsplit

First step is to rsplit (reverse split) the columns by last occurance of `"_"` substring. Then create a multi-index, DEM_HEALTH is `level 0` and PRE, HOS, etc are `level 1`.

```
new_cols = [tuple(i.rsplit('_',1)) for i in df.columns]
new_cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_cols)

df.columns = new_cols
print(df)
```

```
  DEM_HEALTH            
        PRIV OUT PRE HOS
0          0   1   1   1
1          0   1   0   0
2          0   0   1   0
3          0   1   0   0
4          1   0   0   0
5          0   0   1   1
6          1   0   1   0
7          1   0   0   1
8          0   1   0   0
9          0   1   1   0
```

#### 2. Stack and Groupby over level=0

```
data = df[df==1]\
        .stack()\
        .reset_index(-1)\
        .groupby(level=0)['level_1']\
        .apply(list)
```

```
0    [HOS, OUT, PRE]
1              [OUT]
2              [PRE]
3              [OUT]
4             [PRIV]
5         [HOS, PRE]
6        [PRE, PRIV]
7        [HOS, PRIV]
8              [OUT]
9         [OUT, PRE]
Name: level_1, dtype: object
```